# Create Constructor for structure and use it with structure object c#

Tags: c#, .net, struct, constructor

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
    // I am using structure to define values type set 
        public struct Employee
        {
            public int EmpId;
            public string FirstName;
            public string LastName;

    // Here i am checking whether parameter less constructor will work 
            static Employee()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First Object Created");
            }

// Here i am using one more constructor for initializing it with some values later on
            public void Employee(int number, string firsname, string lasname)
            {
                id = number;
                FirstName = firsname;
                LastName = lasname;
            }    
        }    

        // Here i am using the parameterize constructor to assign values mentioned before in the //structure

        class Program {

            Employee emp1 = new Employee(23,"shiva","shankar");            
        }      
    }
```

// Error i am getting is Employee structure doesnt contain constructor that takes 3 args
// The name id doesnt exist in current context
//Employee : member names cannot be same as their enclosing type

Comment: First off you're probably better off using a class, but if you do use a struct do not allow it to be mutable as that will allow you to modify a copy which does not modify the original. (better to not allow mutation and force uses of the struct to assign a new value) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Comment: FYI a general rule of thumb is that if the type contains reference types (like `string`) then it probably should be a reference type.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `id` field in your `Employee` struct, only `EmpId`. Also, [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) in C# can't have a return type:

> A constructor is a method whose name is the same as the name of its
>   type. Its method signature includes only the method name and its
>   parameter list; it does not include a return type.

You should rewrite your code as following

```cs
// Here i am using one more constructor for initializing it with some values later on
public Employee(int number, string firstName, string lastName)
{
    EmpId = number;
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
}
```

Also it makes sense to declare your fields as `private`, or use readonly properties instead, with getters only, initialized in constructor

```cs
public int EmpId { get; }
public string FirstName { get; }
public string LastName { get; }
```

Otherwise your `struct` is mutable. Also it contains a reference type values, like `string`. It's better to introduce an `Employee` class rather than struct

Answer (score 2):

the constructor doesn't have a return value.

```
public Employee(int number, string firsname, string lasname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems it's need to define a new static member, then call that new one, so the static constructor will be triggered soon.

Let's to check this:

```
public static int id = 0;

static Employee()
{
    Console.WriteLine("First Object Created");
}
```

First call:

```
Emploee.id = 1;
Employee emp1 = new Employee(23,"shiva","shankar");

Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}", Employee.id);
Console.WriteLine("emp1.EmpId: {0}", emp1.EmpId);
```

Output:

```
First Object Created
Id: 1;
emp1.EmpId: 23
```

Second call:

```
Employee.id = 2;

// copy emp1 values to var emp2
var emp2 = emp1; // both emp1 and emp2 have same values

// set emp2.EmpId to new value.
emp2.EmpId = 24;

Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}", Employee.id);
Console.WriteLine("emp1.EmpId: {0}", emp1.EmpId);
Console.WriteLine("emp2.EmpId: {0}", emp2.EmpId);
```

Output:

```
Id: 2;
emp1.EmpId: 23
emp2.EmpId: 24
```

Hope this could helps. Cheers!